# Breakpoint not getting hit in VSCode 8.3.0 with Next.js debugger config

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

Breakpoint not getting hit in VSCode 8.3.0 with Next.js debugger config

vscode 8.3.0 does not stop when placing breakpoint in a function

bug with VSCODE 8.3.0 the solution is to downgrade to VSCODE 8.2.3

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82

solution to VSCODE 8.3.0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).